# Creating Android vpn profile

Tags: android

I want to Programmatically create vpn profile; somehow i figure out how to access `android.net.vpnmanager` and `android.net.vpn.vpnprofile` (they are not part of offical API and are part of hide APIs)  but they have no function create new vpn profile. any suggestions?

Comment: you can do only PPTP not the other like L2TP or L2TPIPsec..

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-openvpn-settings/

Comment: it require to root device! thats a big problem!

Comment: Using the hidden APIs means you can never offer support for your customers and a bunch of other problems. This is unreliable approach.

Comment: so what is the solution ? how can i configure vpn for my customers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Hidden APIs is not a good idea as there is no guarantee that with an update they will still work as intended, moreover there is no guarantee that they will work in a consistent manner across different devices manufactured by different vendors.

Android 4.0 ICS has a VPN client API but again it allows you to create your own VPN client. 
The only reason I can think of as to why you cannot access VPN settings just as you will access wifi settings is the inherent nature of VPN connections. Here is a link to the VPN features in ICS4.0. The first part of the document discuss these risks. You can still write your own client for your app.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html

Another approach can be to use a third party VPN client and check if you can pass any actions to it via an intent. My recommendation if you are targeting ICS only will be to go with the client API as that you know how your code is working.

Comment: If you are on < ICS then you do not really have the luxury of an open API and thus accessing the hidden API is the only alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I thinkt that **[VPN Android](http://vpnandroid.net/)** isn't yet on a stable release, there are a couple of other clients besides the built-in there. But there's so many changes between the last versions of Android regarding the VPN and proxy settings. At the beginning there aren't any VPN support at all, then you can only get that rooting your device and now there's a kind of stable native VPN client inside Android but like you noted, lack of documentation in many aspects and other bugs too.

My recommendation would be to wait to create your code after we have a slightly more stable VPN Android and documentation. If you can't or don't want to wait, go forward with that undocumented API, it could change in the future but I don't see any better option right now.

Answer (score 1):

If You are using a phone from Motorola look into using this as it has code to create working vpn connections using L2tp and Pptp

http://developer.motorola.com/docs/Motorola_Enterprise_Device_Management_SDK_Getting_Started/